# How to provide a callback function or block only instead of create an object that conforms to UIPickerViewDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates

I've two ViewControllers, one for data and other to pick data in a `UIPickerView`. So, in the root ViewController I want get the delegate of picker view.
I'm trying this:

RootViewController:

```
 let setReasonVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "setReasonVc") as! SetReasonViewController
 setReasonVc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
 setReasonVc.definesPresentationContext = true
 setReasonVc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
 setReasonVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

 setReasonVc.pickerOptions.delegate = ???? // <- how to?

 self.present(setReasonVc, animated: true, completion: {})
```

ViewController to pick:

```
class SetReasonViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var txtFieldJustificativa: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerOptions: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

     }

}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I had to read the accepted answer's comments to understand what you want, i.e. provide 1 callback function or block only instead of create an object that conforms to UIPickerViewDelegate (because the other methods are getting in the way?)

Comment: ok.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opt1:** You need to create  a var inside  `SetReasonViewController`vc

```
weak var delegate:RootVC?
```

Then when present it

```
setReasonVc.delegate = self
```

after that in `viewDidLoad` of `SetReasonViewController`

```
pickerOptions.delegate = delegate
/**pickerOptions.dataSource = delegate**/ un comment to make `SetReasonViewController ` the dataSource
```

---

```
class RootVC:UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate {
  //here implement didSelectRow
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    }
 }
```

**Opt2:** Another easy option is to do

```
setReasonVc.loadViewIfNeeded()
setReasonVc.pickerOptions.delegate = self
```

> Warning your current code

```
setReasonVc.pickerOptions.delegate = ???? // <- how to?
```

will cause a crash as you access the picker before the vc load which is nil at the moment , so `setReasonVc.loadViewIfNeeded()` will fix it

**Edit:**

```
class RootVC: UIViewController {

     func myNavigate() {

        let setReasonVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "setReasonVc") as! SetReasonViewController
        setReasonVc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true
        setReasonVc.definesPresentationContext = true
        setReasonVc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
        setReasonVc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        setReasonVc.callback = { (ind) in
            print(ind)
        }
        self.present(setReasonVc, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
}

class SetReasonViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var callback:((Int)->())?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
       pickerOptions.delegate = self
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        callback?(row)

    }

}
```

Comment: For this way I must use the interfaces, I thought there was another way.

Comment: I want write Just one function!

Comment: make the delegate implementation inside the root and datasource inside **SetReasonViewController**

Comment: Yes, this I know. I already understand, not have way to make like I wanted.

Comment: setReasonVc.pickerOptions.delegate = { @Override funcs }

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't directly do this because at the time when you instantiate the VC, the views have not loaded yet.

If I were you, I would write a `SetReasonViewControllerDelegate`:

```
protocol SetReasonViewControllerDelegate : class {
    func reasonDidChange(to reason: String)
}
```

And then do this in `RootVC`:

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController, SetReasonViewControllerDelegate {
    func reasonDidChange(to reason: String) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Now in SetReason VC, you set `self` as `delegate`:

```
class SetReasonViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    let reasons = [...]
    weak var delegate: SetReasonViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        pickerOptions.delegate = self
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        delegate?.reasonDidChange(to: reasons[row])
    }
    // other delegate methods...
}
```

When you present the set reason VC, you set `self` as the delegate of that:

```
setReasonVc.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the controller that will fill the data for the picker to conform to [UIPickerViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate) and then just assign it to  `setReasonVc.pickerOptions.delegate`.  You'll also need to set the `setReasonVc.pickerOptions.dataSource` by conforming to [UIPickerViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdatasource).